# Почему два последних пункта меню съезжают вниз?

Tags: html, css

Не могу разобраться, почему при верстке меню два последних пункта "съезжают" вниз http://jsfiddle.net/qxm5B/5/ (видно, если навести мышку). Я предполагаю, что это из-за того, что для пунктов меню задано свойство `display: inline-block;` и съехавшие пункты как бы "перешли" на следующую строку, но не знаю, наверняка, так ли это,  и не могу разобраться, как это поправить. Подскажите, в чем тут может быть дело?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Используйте вместо :

```
display: inline-block;

#nav ul  li {
    float: left;
}
```

Comment: да, большое спасибо, помогло))

Answer (score 2):

Не нужен вам ни какой float. Используйте вертикальное выравнивание

```
#nav ul li {
    vertical-align: top;
    ...
}
```